# How to modify a portion of the url using htacess?

Tags: .htaccess

My URL: www.example.com/store?store=1

Desired URL : www.example.com/store/1

I've seen many answers similar to this on SO but nothing solved my problem as such. Little explanation with the answer would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To covert

- http://example.com/store?store=1

to

- http://example.com/store/1

You can use the following rule in `root/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

#1)externally redirct  "/store?store=foo" to "/store/foo"

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /store/?\?store=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /store/%1? [L,R]
##2)internally redirect the new url "/store/foo" to /store?store=foo##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^store/([^/]+)/?$ /store?store=$1 [NC,L]
```

Note : If you are going to put this in the  `store/.htaccess` just remove the folder name and trailing slash from the #2 rule, just change the pattern `^store/([^/]+)/?$`  to `^([^/]+)/?$` to use the rules in subfolder htacess.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)store=1($|&)
RewriteRule ^www\.example\.com/store$ /www.example.com/store/1?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

I hope it will work

Comment: Thanks ! How will this work, whats the symbol with www in line 2 does, sorry for the noobness but I need to know. And how to make it happen for a site on localhost.

Comment: Just paste this code in your ht-access file and change your domain name in place of www.example.com